# Emacs query-replace with textual transformation

Tags: regex, emacs

I want to find any text in a file that matches a regexp of the form *t*`[A-Z]`*u* (i.e., a match *t* followed by a capital letter and another match *u*, and transform the matched text so that the capital letter is lowercase. For example, for the regexp `x[A-Z]y`

```
xAy
```

becomes

```
xay
```

and

```
xZy
```

becomes

```
xzy
```

Emacs' `query-replace` function allows back-references, but AFAIK not the transformation of the matched text. Is there a built-in function that does this? Does anybody have a short Elisp function I could use?

**UPDATE**

@Marcel Levy has it: `\,` in a replacement expression introduces an (arbitrary?) Elisp expression. E.g., the solution to the above is

```
M-x replace-regexp <RET> x\([A-Z]\)z <RET> x\,(downcase \1)z
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like [Steve Yegge](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/) actually already posted the answer to this a few years back: ["Shiny and New: Emacs 22."](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/06/shiny-and-new-emacs-22.html) Scroll down to "Changing Case in Replacement Strings" and you'll see his example code using the `replace-regexp` function.

The general answer is that you use "\," to call any lisp expression as part of the replacement string, as in `\,(capitalize \1)`. Reading the help text, it looks like it's only in interactive mode, but that seems like the one place where this would be most necessary.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to qrr in this case is recording a macro and replaying it. (isearch-forward-regexp, select the character, downcase-region.) I find on the fly macros easier, since you get immediate feedback if your regexp is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this with a macro as well, but only because executing code from within a replacement string for a regular expression is very unintuitive to me.  If you're writing a batch script or something that needs to go very fast, \, is certainly the way to go.